# Search a UIView hierarchy using functional Swift

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I've written a function that iterates through the superviews of a given UIView to obtain a reference to a specific UIView subclass if present (in this instance, UITableView). This works fine using imperative style but it does seem to be a problem that would lend itself very well to 'Railway Oriented Programming'. As I'm still getting my head around functional, is anyone able to suggest a more elegant functional version of this function?

```
func findTableView(var view: UIView) -> UITableView? {
    var table: UITableView? = nil
    while table == nil {
        guard let superView = view.superview else { return nil }
        view = superView
        table = view as? UITableView
    }
    return table
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
func findTableView(view: UIView) -> UITableView? {
    return view as? UITableView ?? view.superview.flatMap(findTableView)
}
```

---

This code is just a short-cut of:

```
func findTableView(view: UIView) -> UITableView? {
    if let tableView = view as? UITableView {
        return tableView
    }
    else {
        let superview = view.superview
        if superview == nil {
            return nil
        }
        else {
            return findTableView(superview!)
        }
    }
}
```

Using ["Nil Coalescing Operator"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) and [`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Optional_Enumeration/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enumm/Optional/s:FSq7flatMapu__rFGSqq__FzFzq_GSqqd___GSqqd___) method on `Optional` enum.

Comment: That's it! I knew if would be more concise. I don't suppose you could you elaborate on this? I'm having a slight conceptual issue understanding what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks! Obvious when you see the expanded version. The use of flatmap() was confusing me but now I realise it's a rather cunning way of handling the nil event when you run out of superviews.

Answer (score 4):

[Swift find superview of given class with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705819/swift-find-superview-of-given-class-with-generics/41372263#41372263)

*Swift 3/4*

```
extension UIView {

    func superview<T>(of type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return superview as? T ?? superview.compactMap { $0.superview(of: type) }
    }

    func subview<T>(of type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return subviews.compactMap { $0 as? T ?? $0.subview(of: type) }.first
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let tableView = someView.superview(of: UITableView.self)
let tableView = someView.subview(of: UITableView.self)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** This is for searching through the **sub**views not **super**views

You could try a recursive functional approach without a while. Don't know if that is what you are looking for.

```
func findTableView(view: UIView) -> UITableView? {
    if view is UITableView {
        return view as? UITableView
    } else {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let res = findTableView(subview) {
                return res
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Edit 2 + 3:**  Made the function simpler

Comment: I actually did think of that as the problem would seem to lend itself well to it but I found it actually made my code slightly bulkier and harder to read. I was thinking that i could use a recursive 'pipeline' if that makes sense: get superview -> if no view, exit with nil otherwise) -> if superview return superview otherwise repeat. I'm not sure if I've made myself clear as I'm not up on the terminology. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: oh i just realized you want to search "up" and not "down"

Comment: No problem :-) Thanks anyway